# K menu unresponsive

Tags: menu

Sometimes my system gets into a state where the K menu is unresponsive - clicking on the big K doesn't do anything. I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  How can I kick-start it?  (I'm using the Application Menu interface, in case that maters.)  The system doesn't seem to be hung generally, and **top**  in a virtual consoledoesn't show anything obvious.

Addendum: I've discovered, though, that if I right-click the K, choose a different application interface, again right-click on the K, and choose "Application Menu", I can get it back.